# Can you use somebody else's `/efs` folder?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

So, assume that there are two Galaxy S3 phones (i9300)s. One of em has a "No Service", "Baseband Unknown" problem while the other works like a charm. Both of them are rooted and flashed with custom ROMs.  (CM11 and CM12).

So, if the phone with proper `/efs` makes a nandroid backup of `/efs` and then that backup is restored in the phone having issues, then this should technically work.

Question is, will it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that partition contains IMEI information and you do not want to be duplicating their phone on the network.

Comment: @MatthewRead Is there a way to change just the IMEI so it matches the one on my phone? (under the battery)

Comment: You may be able to [hex edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) the partition, but before you start messing with it and definitely before you attempt copying one to the other, back up the original /efs (with nandroid or `dd`) and definitely check out the [laws](https://www.congress.gov/bill/105th-congress/senate-bill/493) in your country to make sure such [activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_cloning) is legal.

Comment: @fattire have a look at [EFS Pro](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/orig-development/tool-updated-09-06-14-efs-professional-t1308546). Using this, I can change the IMEI to my own, right?

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work, because there is cant be two phones with same IMEI codes and every single phone probably has special modem codes so efs from one phone won't work in other phone

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you have download a Rom, there is many files as you can see like :

- **PDA**
- **PHONE**
- **CSC**

this is in `ODIN`.
So, you need `Modem` or `CSC` for flash.

> (But this is for Flash on `Stock Rom` and need `3 file`).and also, for
>   get back and test for need or not need **Z3X** box, just back to
>   Stock rom and tell us your problem is solved with Stock or not.this
>   texts are, for more information.and help you for install Stock without
>   this problem.anyway.

As i said in chat, take a backup from `efs` (from worked device) and install it with recovery.

technically, it will work.But, this is sometimes Harassment you and need money for solved with `z3x` :)

hope your problem solved with flash `efs`.